# Regex - add space between replaced characters

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex `@"\bAND\b|\bOR\b|""|\(|\)"` that strips out certain words or characters from a string. The problem I have is that if the following text is used:

*Over ear headphones"OR"on ear headphones*

When I use regex.replace, the regex successfully strings out 'OR' but the two queries will be mashed together

*Over ear headphoneson ear headphones*

This only happens when there isn't a space between the word between the word I want to strip and the other query terms. Is there an elegant way to add spaces between keywords I want to strip, if none exist.

Comment: Try [`@"(?:\s*\b(AND|OR)\b\s*|[()""\s])+"`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%5cs*%5cb%28AND%7cOR%29%5cb%5cs*%7c%5b%28%29%22%22%5cs%5d%29%2b&i=Over+ear+headphones%22OR%22on+ear+headphones%0d%0aOver+ear+headphones+%22OR%22+on+ear+headphones&r=+) and replace with a space.

Answer (score 1):

I know that it may sound silly, but have you tried replacing this with a single space instead of just removing it?

Answer (score 0):

Add a space regardless in the replacement text, then create a subsequent regex replace to strip out 2 or more spaces when this condition is not hit.

That way you are guaranteed that one space will be between each of the words.

This is a basic example (without your quoted `"OR"`) for brevity but the concept is the same:

```
Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(txt, "OR", " "), @"\s\s", " ")
```

Result

```
Over ear headphones on ear headphones
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if you just match any spaces in the first place, like: `Regex.Replace(txt, @"OR\s*", " ");`? Then you wouldn't have to call Regex.Replace twice.

Comment: @JulianA put it in as an answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should preserve the existing format (as well as can be expected).

*To use non-linebreak whitespace, substitute the `\s` with `[^\s\r\n]`

or similar.*

---

Just optionally consume a single whitespace on either side of the expression,   then replace with a whitespace of your choice.

This is done on items surrounded with text.

```
A<sp><item>B     => A<sp>B  
A<sp><item>B<sp> => A<sp>B  
A<item><sp>B     => A<sp>B  
A<item>B         => A<sp>B
```

For items at the beginning or end of the string
replace with the empty string.

This is the regex `@"(^)?\s?(?:\b(?:AND|OR)\b|[()""])+\s?($)?"`

Expanded

```
 ( ^ )?                        # (1)
 \s? 
 (?:
      \b 
      (?: AND | OR )
      \b 
   |  [()"] 
 )+
 \s? 
 ( $ )?                        # (2)
```

C#

```
string sTrg = @"""Over ear headphones""OR""on ear headphones""";
Console.WriteLine("{0}", sTrg);

Regex rX = new Regex(@"(^)?\s?(?:\b(?:AND|OR)\b|[()""])+\s?($)?");
Console.WriteLine("{0}", rX.Replace(sTrg,
    delegate (Match m) {
       if (m.Groups[1].Success || m.Groups[2].Success)
           return "";
       return " ";
   }));
```

Output

```
"Over ear headphones"OR"on ear headphones"
Over ear headphones on ear headphones
```